# can't prevent redirection even with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false and safe_mode is off

Tags: php, redirect, curl

Note: this is not a duplicate, i have been searching for almost two days on a solution.

I have a simple page with a redirection. and i can't prevent the redirection even with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` set to False.

My safe_mode is off

Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.flickr.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
echo curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Check your response. There may be meta or js redirects.

Comment: Set also `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` as `zero` to [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: @Phantom: the js redirects are not followed as curl doesn't render javascript code. I don't know about meta, but I would guess that even these will not be followed, as curl only returns the webpage content.